# Ubuntu sometimes fails to recognise network card on wake from suspend

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi, devices, lshw

**Issue**

Sometimes, when I wake my computer from a suspended state, it fails to connect to the Wi-Fi and it appears that my computer fails to recognise my network card.

Update 2022-05-25: This has persisted after replacing the network card.

**Troubleshooting Efforts**

Looking at the networking settings panel, no Wi-Fi networks are listed. Toggling Wi-Fi/Networking on and off does not fix the problem. On logging out, no symbol for network settings is shown in the top-right indicator bar. Logging back in does not resolve the issue.

Restarting the computer almost always fixes the problem. However, the first time this happened, after I restarted the computer the option for 'Enable Wi-Fi' was missing entirely from the network menu. I ran `lshq -C network` and next to my wireless card it said ‘UNCLAIMED’. After a second restart, the card continued to work as normal.

Re: [@chili555's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403856/ubuntu-sometimes-fails-to-recognise-network-card-on-wake-from-suspend#comment2437918_1403856):

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
```

`sudo modprobe ath9k` produced no output.

Update 2022-05-03: The problem got worse, with the card dropping off repeatedly and reboots no longer fixing it. `dmesg` was showing a chip reset failure loop whenever the card dropped off, which was also briefly displayed on screen just before the machine powered off:

```
⋮
[20374.812295] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[20374.886842] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[20374.999529] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[20374.999536] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[20375.074303] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[20375.187186] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[20375.187192] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[20375.262785] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[20375.377579] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[20375.377584] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
[20375.453445] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[20375.567989] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
⋮
```

Whilst my desktop PC is stationary, I do have my home Wi-Fi network set to automatic band selection. [This RedHat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1311680) suggests the issue happens when changing network whilst suspended (in the context of moving a laptop), so I wonder if part of the problem is the computer trying to connect to a different band on wake than it was connected to before.

[This Debian thread](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=646305) is the only thing I could find that seemed to be describing the exact same issue that I'm facing, but none of the suggestions (which are largely related to laptop power management settings) were any help.

I did notice that when I rebooted and entered my disk decryption password, an `fsck` prompt would very briefly flicker below the Ubuntu logo before I booted into the OS. I used `forcefsck` and the prompt stayed on screen until it got to about 70%, then booted into the OS, and then completed the remaining 30% when I rebooted again. This has not fixed the problem.

Update 2022-05-25: I replaced the network card with a new one (see Hardware Specs below). The issue is happening less frequently, and it has yet to persist past a restart, but it hasn't solved the problem entirely so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.

When the wireless connectivity drops my CPU usage repeatedly spikes as (I assume) the system keeps trying and failing to re-engage it. My `dmesg` errors seem to have changed with the new network card as well:

```
[66147.257420] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x776a, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[66147.257439] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[66147.257455] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[66147.257458] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[66147.257591] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[66147.257593] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[66147.257595] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[66147.257597] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[66147.257598] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[66147.257600] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[66147.257601] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[66147.257602] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[66147.257604] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[66147.257605] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[66147.257607] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[66147.257608] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[66147.257610] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[66147.257611] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[66147.257613] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[66147.257614] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[66147.257615] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[66147.257617] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[66147.257618] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[66147.257620] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[66147.257621] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[66147.257623] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[66147.257624] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[66147.257626] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[66147.257627] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[66147.257629] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[66147.257630] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[66147.257632] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[66147.257633] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[66147.257634] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[66147.257636] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[66147.257637] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[66147.257639] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[66147.257640] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[66147.257642] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[66147.257690] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[66147.257692] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[66147.257694] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[66147.257695] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[66147.257697] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[66147.257699] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[66147.257700] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[66147.257702] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[66147.257703] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[66147.257705] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[66147.257706] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[66147.257708] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[66147.257709] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000121C9 | frame pointer
[66147.257711] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[66147.257712] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[66147.257714] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[66147.257728] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[66147.257729] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[66147.257743] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000776A | IML/ROM data1
[66147.257757] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[66147.257765] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[66147.257770] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[66147.257775] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[66147.257781] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[66147.257786] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[66147.257791] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[66147.257796] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[66147.257801] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[66147.257806] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[66147.257811] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[66147.257818] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[66147.257825] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[66147.257833] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[66147.257837] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[66147.257839] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[66147.257840] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[66147.929144] ata19: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[66149.012674] ata19: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[66149.202661] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: mac start retry 2
```

**Hardware Specs**

- Network card: <s>Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 PCI-E network card (in use for ~10 years)</s> Replaced with TP-Link ARCHER TX50E AX3000
- OS: <s>Ubuntu 21.10</s> Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Can you boot into an earlier kernel version and, if so, does the wireless work? Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ath9k` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555 My wireless is working fine now following another restart - my question is whether I should be concerned or not about the fact I lost it in the first place (i.e., can network adapters fail like HDDs, and if so is there anything equivalent to a SMART test I can run to see if mine is having problems?)

Comment: Wireless devices can and do fail, but not like HDDs or SDs wich fail gradually as sectors fail but the remainder are still available. Wireless devices, ethernet devices, mice, keyboards, etc. may work intermittently and, one day, don't work at all. I know of no test method. These devices are fairly inexpensive and easy to replace. As well, you could have a backup USB wireless at the ready.

Comment: I've amended the question - this has become a regular issue, seeming to hit when I wake the computer from a suspended state (though not every time).

Comment: "Update 2022-05-03: The problem got worse, with the card dropping off repeatedly and reboots no longer fixing it. dmesg was showing a chip reset failure loop" I still believe it's a hardware failure that will soon be permanent.

Comment: @chili555 Yeah, I think you're probably right - time to go card shopping.

Comment: @chili555 Limited success with replacing the card - I've added an update to the question

Comment: "Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode" My fully updated 22.04 system contains three newer than -66 firmware files. Please do a sudo apt update and see if *linux-firmware* gets an update. Reboot and show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 There were some packages to update, but no `linux-firmware`. `dmesg` still logs ‘`iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm`’

Comment: Please see: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/73387 Please try renaming all the firmware files from -66 forward to get the driver to load -63. Check: `ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep ty-a0-gf-a0` Rename all more recent than -63: `cd /usr/lib/firmware` and: `sudo mv iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode  iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.bak` Repeat for versions -67, -68 and -71 if present. Check again: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Any improvement?

Comment: @chili555 Deleting those firmwares to force a load of -64 seems to have done the trick. However, the issue returned when I updated my software and the computer started to use -66 again. The file for -71 was present, so I'm not sure why my computer insists on loading -66. Is there a way I can force a specific firmware version, so I can bring my computer back up-to-date and see if -71 resolves the issue?

Comment: I am quite confident that one of the updates was the package *linux-firmware* and that the files you renamed were replaced by the newer version. I suggest that you repeat the renames (NOT deletes) I suggested above and  see if the wireless works again.

Comment: The driver only loads -66 because that's hard-coded into the driver iwlwifi as the highest version it can use. It tries every version from -66 back to -59 until it finds and loads one. Versions -67, -68 and -71 are included in *linux-firmware* in the event the driver iwlwifi is rewritten to use some newer version.

Comment: Okay, I think that's it - I'll just hold off updating my firmware until 22.10 releases (presumably with a newer version of iwlwifi). Do you want to submit an answer summarising what you've put here so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/73387

Please try renaming all the firmware files from -66 forward to get the driver to load -63. Check:

```
 ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep ty-a0-gf-a0
```

Rename all more recent than -63:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware 
sudo mv iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.bak
```

Repeat for versions -67, -68 and -71 if present. Reboot and check again:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Is there any improvement?

Please note that the package linux-firmware is updated from time to time. When this happens your .bak files will be over-written and your wireless will, once again stop working. In that case repeat the steps above and reboot.