# No intenet w/ VPN after suspend Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, vpn, 22.04, iwlwifi

A few days ago I upgraded 20.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04 and noticed that after suspend there's no internet connection over wifi. Only reboot helps. Tuning off and on wifi drivers by `modprobe -r iwlwifi` doesn't have any effect. I tried kernels `5.13`, `5.15`, `5.17.5`, `5.18.6` - no change. Tried restarting `NetworkManager.service` - same behavior.

Here' s `lspci -v` output [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Y31mYuzN)

Here's log of `dmesg -TW` [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UgsUYufs) (I was connected to vpn and left it to enter sleep mode. After logging in there was no internet over connected wifi and the following log.)

One more, longer, log from last night - [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5jDmem0A)

***UPDATE:*** It's related when I had VPN connection turned on. If I let it got into sleep on regular wifi connection, internet access remains after suspend.

Noteworthy: After suspend there's no connection neither via VPN, nor without it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Did you try restarting the network manager from the command line? `nmcli network off` and then `nmcli network on` ? I often have to do it after disconnecting  a VPN.

Comment: @Raffles, tried it - no effect. I doubt it's related to VPN, as I remember it happened not on VPN connection.
Moreover, I doubt it is related to wi-fi drivers

Comment: @Raffles, Update:
you were right about VPN. Just tested it and when not on VPN, internet access remains after suspend. 
However, `nmcli network on` doesn't help

Comment: You first have to use `nmcli network off` and then `nmcli network on`. Also check if you can disable the VPN network lock which is a feature that might be enabled by default. What it does is lock you out of the internet when you lose the connection which would happen when your machine goes to sleep.

Comment: Sure, I did both commands :-)
I am not sure whether there is built in function in Ubuntu for (dis)enabling VPN network lock, but I don't have one enabled in my Cisco Anyconnect. ([image](https://ibb.co/hfMN6YS)).
And as a note, I had the same pipeline in Ubuntu 20.04 and after suspend I had full internet access w/ or w/o VPN

Comment: Take a look at this post [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403856/ubuntu-sometimes-fails-to-recognise-network-card-on-wake-from-suspend/1416597#1416597] and see if it helps you.

Comment: Are you using a built-in client like OpenVPN or an applcation from your VPN provider? If the latter and it has features such as a kill switch, DNS leak protection, etc., it can cause lots of connectivity issues.Once I uninstalled my provider's app, searched for and removed any remaining commands, and manually configured an OPenVPN connection, it's been trouble-free.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check for connections left by the killswitch, or ipv6 leak protection.

`nmcli connection show --active`

check for any of such networks
then

Delete them respectively.

`nmcli connection delete <Connection name>`